# Extract translations from twig templates with Gulp or PHP task

Tags: javascript, php, gulp, twig

In my framework I'm using the PHP Silex Framework with Twig templates and translations. How can I extract those translations variables with a Gulp or PHP task?

Small code example:

```html
<h3 class="box-heading">{% trans 'Content' %}</h3>
```

The only solution I could find on the web was the pro version of the PoEditor.

Comment: What part of that line of code  do you want extracted?  And by "extracted" what do you mean precisely?

Comment: I want to add it to an existing .po file so my team can translate the strings.